# How to display a higher value yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

how to display a higher value, for example, if `mass > volume` then the `mass price` appears in gridview, if `mass < volume` then the `volume price` appears. 
I use source code like this but still can't.

```
    [
        'label' => 'Tarif',
        'format' => 'Currency',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            if ($volume= $model['rate'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] / 4000)
                return $volume;
            else if ($mass= $model['rate'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'])
                return $mass;
            else if ($volume > $mass)
                return $volume;
            else if ($volume < $mass)
                return $mass;
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[
    'label' => 'Tarif',
    'format' => 'Currency',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $volume = $model['rate'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] / 4000;
        $mass = $model['rate'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'];

        return $mass > $volume? $mass : $volume;
    }
],
```

Check this out and let me know, please make sure that your calculations are correct.

**Edited**

```
[
    'label' => 'Tarif',
    'format' => 'Currency',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        // Please note that the $model will be object not an array
        $volume = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] / 4000;
        $mass = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'];

        return $mass > $volume? $mass : $volume;
    }
],
```

Make sure that your calculations are correct. Reference https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets

Comment: how to implement this return $mass > $volume? $mass : $volume; I want to add this variable $kubik = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] /10000 + $model->admin_fee;
into 3 comparisons

Comment: Please give a proper explanation of your calculations, then only I can help you.

Comment: I want to add $kubik, so there are 3 comparisons that were previously $ mass and $ volume. my calculations : if  mass > volume > kubik then the mass price appears , if volume > kubik > mass then the volume price appears, if kubik > massa > volume then the kubik price appears

Comment: So you have to return the highest value, you can simply use `max()` but make sure the values are comparable otherwise play with if else conditions.

`return max([$mass, $volume, $kubik]); // It will give the highest value`

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. it works for me and your references is very helpful